# How to set the value of a symbol in a package

Tags: packages

I am writing a package like this:

```
BeginPackage["HNotation2`"];

Begin["`Private`"];

HTransR=3;

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

When I load the package, it seems that the symbol `HTransR` is not defined.
Is there something wrong with the way that I'm assigning a value to the symbol in the package?

Comment: First, it should be ``Begin["Private`"];``. Afterwards, you will find `HTransR` in the context ``"HNotation2`Private`"``. Unless you let appear the symbol `HTransR` already before ``Begin["Private`"];``, you have to refer to it by ``HNotation2`Private`HTransR`` from outside that package.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher - I am confused by the first sentence of your comment.

Comment: but it **should** be ```Begin["`Private`"]```

Comment: @JasonB. Oops. Sorry. I did not know about that possibility (good to know!). I tend to use the full context path (``Begin["HNotation2 `Private`"];``), but of course that is a bit redundant and error prone. Once again, sorry guys for the confusion caused by me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With respect, I believe `` Begin["`Private`"] `` is acceptable, and perhaps preferable. `` Begin["Private`"] `` establishes a context `` "Private`" ``. This is fine, but if two packages do that they will share that context. `` Begin["`Private`"] `` establishes context `` HNotation2`Private` ``. This will be private to this package only.

The reason `HTransR` appears to be undefined is that it is defined within context `` HNotation2`Private` ``, which is not on the `$ContextPath` -- it can be accessed by its full name as `` HNotation2`Private`HTranR ``.

If you wish it to be accessible by its short nme, you could place a usage statement for it before `` Begin["`Private`"] ``, or just define it there. Then it will be in the package context, which is placed on the context path when the package is loaded.

Comment: @Kuba, thanks for the edit.